# Accessing OPENJSON parsed JSON multiple times in a stored procedure?

Tags: json, sql-server, open-json

Consider this JSON:

```
{
    "Name": "Alice",
    "Relations": [
        {
            "RelationId": 1,
            "Value": "one"
        },
        {
            "RelationId": 2,
            "Value": "two"
        }
    ]
}
```

I pass this JSON to a stored procedure where it is parsed and the names are inserted:

```
-- parse JSON
WITH [source]
AS (SELECT *
    FROM
        OPENJSON(@json)
        WITH
        (
            [Name] VARCHAR(50),
            [Relations] VARCHAR(MAX)
        ) -- end json WITH
) -- end WITH [source] AS

-- insert Name
INSERT INTO dbo.names
(
    [Name]
)
SELECT [s].[Name]
FROM [source] s;
```

Next, I want to insert the relations, so first I have to `OPENJSON` the `[Relations]` part:

```
WITH [relationsSource]
AS (SELECT *
    FROM
        -- now, here is the problem: the CTE (common table expression)
        -- named [source] isn't available anymore
        OPENJSON(<how to access [source].[Relations] here?)
        WITH
        (
            [RelationId] INT,
            [Value] VARCHAR(50)
        ) -- end json WITH
) -- end WITH [relationsSource]
```

I know I could do something like `OPENJSON(@json, '$Relations')`. But this would parse the whole `@json` again to search for the `$Relations` path instead of only parsing the previously extracted `[source].[Relations]`.

Is there any solution that allows me using something like

```
OPENJSON([source].[Relations]) -- pass only the Relations subset of @json
```

so that `OPENJSON` doesn't have to parse the complete `@json` again?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Json NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
{
    "Name": "Alice",
    "Relations": [
        {
            "RelationId": 1,
            "Value": "one"
        },
        {
            "RelationId": 2,
            "Value": "two"
        }
    ]
}
'

SELECT persons.Id PersonId
    , persons.Name
    , relations.RelationId
    , relations.Value
INTO #JsonToFlatTable
FROM (
    -- sub-query to retrieve the root person.Name and the array of relations
    SELECT *
    , Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY Name) Id -- Add a fake ID or use some kind of mapping with an existing table. 
    FROM OPENJSON(@json, N'lax $') 
    WITH (
        [Name] VARCHAR(255) N'lax $.Name'
        , Relations nvarchar(MAX) N'$.Relations' AS JSON  
    )
) persons
-- Use openjson on the subset of relations to retrieve the RelationId and Value
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(persons.Relations, N'lax $')
    WITH(
        RelationId INT N'lax $.RelationId'
        , Value VARCHAR(255) N'lax $.Value'
    ) relations 

-- Maybe set IDENTITY_INSERT ON
INSERT INTO Person(Id, Name)
SELECT DISTINCT PersonId
    , Name
FROM #JsonToFlatTable
-- Maybe set IDENTITY_INSERT OFF

INSERT INTO Relation(PersonId, RelationId, Value)
SELECT PersonId
    , RelationId
    , Value
FROM #JsonToFlatTable
```

**Output**

| PersonId | Name | RelationId | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice | 1 | one |
| 1 | Alice | 2 | two |

You specify a [schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/use-openjson-with-an-explicit-schema-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) using the `WITH` clause. And you will parse only the subset relations with `OPENJSON` a second time.

The `AS JSON` on the line `Relations nvarchar(MAX) N'$.Relations' AS JSON` is critical for this to work. If `AS JSON` is not specified, you'll get `NULL` instead of the array.

From the microsoft docs above:

> Notice how the AS JSON clause causes values to be returned as JSON objects instead of scalar values in col5 and array_element.

Parsing everything in one go isn't possible if the array size is dynamic. If it's a fixed size you could create columns for every known index, but this isn't maintainable. When the array size changes, you'll need to change your code.

To then put the extracted data in a corresponding table you can use a temp table and fill the corresponding tables. You may need [Identity_Insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).  Or you can use an [output clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples) to retrieve the generated ID from the persons table.

Comment: Thank you for that detailed reply! Unfortunately it shows me, that I might have reduced my question too much. I need to insert the data in two different tables, so `Name`goes in `dbo.names` as given, but for the relations there's a second table `dbo.relations` and every row there needs to be (<id of inserted Name>,<Value>,<RelationId>). Not sure if I should ask a new question though or modify my existing one ): Meanwhile, I am wondering if `Relations nvarchar(MAX) N'$.Relations' AS JSON` doesn't already parse the Relations (as they are returned as a JSON object) ?

Comment: Also, do you know why `AS JSON` is needed for the Relations and what's the difference between JSON as a string and JSON with `AS JSON`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.  The `JSON_VALUE` function selects the single instance of 'Name'.  The `OPENJSON` tvf specifies the path to the 'Relations' object and provides the column definitions.

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) = N'
{
    "Name": "Alice",
    "Relations": [
        {
            "RelationId": 1,
            "Value": "one"
        },
        {
            "RelationId": 2,
            "Value": "two"
        }
    ]
}'


select json_value(@json, '$.Name') as [Name], j.*
from openjson(@json, '$.Relations') 
              with (RelationId          int,
                    [Value]             nvarchar(4000)) j;
```

Output

```
Name    RelationId  Value
Alice   1           one
Alice   2           two
```